# How to modify Alexnet Architecture for GreyScale Images?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I need to extract features from fc7 from alexnet architecture. But I only have greyscale images. How can I modify alexnet for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the expected input tensor from 3 channels to 1.  You can leave the rest of the model alone.  If this over-fits your data set (you haven't specified your input; AlexNet was built for ImageNet), then try reducing the depths of the first two convolution layers by 2x.